# NestJS Prisma client unable to import generated types

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I am using Prisma with NestJs and after defining my model and running npx prisma generate, I can infer from the types when I import the generated type:

```
import { FulfilmentReport, FulfilmentReportCreateInput } from "@prisma/client";
```

Type of FulfilmentReportCreateInput (When hovered):

```
type FulfilmentReportCreateInput = {
    experimentId: string;
    variantId: string;
    fileName: string;
    reportType: string;
    startDate: string | Date;
    endDate: string | Date;
}
```

My schema.prisma:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model FulfilmentReport {
  jobId        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  experimentId String   
  variantId    String
  fileName     String
  reportType   String
  startDate    DateTime
  endDate      DateTime
}
```

However the issue now is that I have an error prompting that FulfilmentReportCreateInput is not an exported member when I can see it's type?

> src/fulfilment-report/fulfilment-report.service.ts:2:28 - error
> TS2305: Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member
> 'FulfilmentReportCreateInput'.
>
> import { FulfilmentReport, FulfilmentReportCreateInput } from
> "@prisma/client";

Is this a typescript issue that it is unable to find the generated class? Have been stuck on this for some time now and could use some help

Answer (score 2):

From Prisma [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety#importing-generated-types):

> You can import the Prisma namespace and use dot notation to access types and utilities

So instead of

```
import { 
  FulfilmentReport, 
  FulfilmentReportCreateInput, 
} from "@prisma/client"
```

write

```
import { 
  FulfilmentReport, 
  Prisma,
} from "@prisma/client"
```

and then use `Prisma.FulfilmentReportCreateInput`

```
async createFulfilmentReport(data: Prisma.FulfilmentReportCreateInput): Promise<FulfilmentReport> {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem yesterday. I solved the problem by updating my Prisma client package. I hope that helps you.

Comment: What do you mean about updating your Prisma client package?

Comment: What I mean is; I updated the `@prisma/client` npm package and that solved my problem